# Using Perl, how can I extract from a log file only the errors that happened during a specific minute?

Tags: perl, loops, pattern-matching

The scenario is that we need to read the number of errors for a particular minute. Each minute can contain hundreds of the same error. After the minute has matched, the total is placed into an array, then the next second is matched.

I am trying to speed up the process by where I need to read in lines from a 300MB file. The file is a log file with every line starting with a HHMMSS.blah format. The current script I have created uses unix's cat with a grep for the HHMM lines so for example 0945, which will then place this data into an array, which contain a complete minute from the log.

From here I then read the array 60 times (one for every second) in a loop, which takes a very long time as the extracts can be around 40,000 lines of data and you are probably cringing by now :)

As I read the array, I then match each second and then add this to a counter for that second, then before the next loop add it to an array and end up with 60 values in an array. (one for every second)

I have a cut down example of the code I am using here, but whilst this works, there has got to be a much better way to only read the array once and not 60 times, but I am not sure how this could be done and am looking for an expert to offer some suggestions on doing this please.

Thank you.

```
Code example
============

my $LOG     = "Logfile.log";    # Log File size is around 300Mb
my $HM      = "0903";
my $MIN         = "60"
my $LOOPCNT     = "0";

# Log File example, with thousands or lines with the same starting time and increasing every second over the hour, then logfile rotated
#160012.serverid.code.stuff error_1
# ....
# .....
#160013.serverid.code.stuff error_2
#160014.serverid.code.stuff error_3

# Using UNIX cat and grep as it seems faster than perl open / read then extracting the hour/min from the full 1 hour log to reduce the size of the data to read.
$RAW = `cat $LOG | grep ^$HM`;

@split_raw = split(/\n/,$RAW);


# Once we have the log. we then read the same array over 60 times (around 40,000 lines)
while ($LOOPCNT < $MIN) {                      
    $COUNTER = sprintf("%02d",$LOOPCNT);
    foreach $RAWLINE(@split_raw) {
        chomp $RAWLINE;
        if ($RAWLINE =~ /^$HM$COUNTER/ && $RAWLINE =~ /error_1/) {
            $ERROR1++;
        } elsif ($RAWLINE =~ /^$HM$COUNTER/ && $RAWLINE =~ /error_2/) {
            $ERROR2++;
        } elsif ($RAWLINE =~ /^$HM$COUNTER/ && $RAWLINE =~ /error_3/) {
            $ERROR3++;
        } elsif ($RAWLINE =~ /^$HM$COUNTER/ && $RAWLINE =~ /error_4/) {
            $ERROR4++;
        }
     }
     push @ARRAY_1,"$ERROR1";
     push @ARRAY_2,"$ERROR2";
     push @ARRAY_3,"$ERROR3";
     push @ARRAY_4,"$ERROR4";
     $LOOPCNT++;
}
```

The result is then pushed out into googles graphing tool to graph the minute.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking several different methods of parsing the info from the lines--e.g. using `index` or `rindex` to search for strings rather than a regex? You have a big enough data set to test it on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than looping over the entire result set for each second, just parse the second on the way through the data. As a side note, I hope you're not actually using variables called `ARRAY_2` and etc in your code, that smells of bad structure.

```
open my $log, "<", $LOG or die $!;
while(<$log>) {
    next unless m/^$HM(\d{2})/;
    # seconds and arrays both start at 0, so this is an acceptable array index
    my $seconds = $1;

    $ARRAY_1[$seconds] ++ if m/error_1/;
    $ARRAY_2[$seconds] ++ if m/error_2/;
    $ARRAY_3[$seconds] ++ if m/error_3/;
    $ARRAY_4[$seconds] ++ if m/error_4/;
}
```

Comment: I'd also try using `index` and `rindex` instead of regexps as substring searches are frequently quicker.

Comment: @ialarmedalien That would be a good thing to try if profiling shows that the program is spending a lot of time evaluating a certain regex. I expect that with this sort of program the time is going to be spent almost entirely reading the file.

Comment: Hi, Thanks everyone for your feedback. I will take a look at all of these methods. I am limited to the what I have in Perl libraries so will also see if Data::Dumper exists, but I will definitely start here. Yes my coding is not great, but trying to learn more and more all the time. Cheers everyone.

Comment: This method works VERY well indeed. My script now takes 17 seconds to complete instead of 113 seconds. Awesome!!!! Thank you once again to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Do your counting once:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
my %counter; # by hhmm and error

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    my ($hhmm, $error) = ($line =~ m{
            \A
            ( [0-9]{4} ) # very loosely matching hour and minute here
            \S+
            \s
            ( \S+ ) # very loosely matching error information
            $
    }x) or next;
    $counter{ $hhmm }{ $error } += 1;
}

print Dumper \%counter;


__DATA__
# some header
160012.serverid.code.stuff error_1
160013.serverid.code.stuff error_2
160014.serverid.code.stuff error_3
160112.serverid.code.stuff error_1
160113.serverid.code.stuff error_2
160114.serverid.code.stuff error_3
160212.serverid.code.stuff error_1
160213.serverid.code.stuff error_2
160214.serverid.code.stuff error_3
```

#### Output:

```
$ ./lpo.pl
$VAR1 = {
          '1600' => {
                      'error_1' => 1,
                      'error_2' => 1,
                      'error_3' => 1
                    },
          '1601' => {
                      'error_1' => 1,
                      'error_3' => 1,
                      'error_2' => 1
                    },
          '1602' => {
                      'error_1' => 1,
                      'error_2' => 1,
                      'error_3' => 1
                    }
        };
```

If you want only a specific time, check for that after matching `hhmm`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper count_errors_for_hhmm(\*DATA, '1602');

sub count_errors_for_hhmm {
    my $fh = shift;
    my $hhmm_wanted = shift;

    my %counter; # by hhmm and error
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        my ($hhmm, $error) = ($line =~ m{
                \A
                ( [0-9]{4} ) # very loosely matching hour and minute here
                \S+
                \s
                ( \S+ ) # very loosely matching error information
                $
        }x) or next;
        if (defined $hhmm_wanted) {
            next unless $hhmm eq $hhmm_wanted;
        }
        $counter{ $hhmm }{ $error } += 1;
    }

    return \%counter;
}

__DATA__
# some header
160012.serverid.code.stuff error_1
160013.serverid.code.stuff error_2
160014.serverid.code.stuff error_3
160112.serverid.code.stuff error_1
160113.serverid.code.stuff error_2
160114.serverid.code.stuff error_3
160212.serverid.code.stuff error_1
160213.serverid.code.stuff error_2
160214.serverid.code.stuff error_3
```

#### Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1602' => {
                      'error_3' => 1,
                      'error_1' => 1,
                      'error_2' => 1
                    }
        };
```

This should be many orders of magnitude faster than what you are doing right now. Opening the log file, and passing the filehandle to the subroutine is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

For test, i generated an logfile like:

```
102135.server11.code.stuff error_0
102135.server17.code.stuff error_6
102135.server18.code.stuff error_3
```

where for each second are 700 errors (approx 42.000 lines per minute), with size about 900MB and with 26M lines.

```
$ ls -l LOG
-rw-r--r--  1 jm  staff  901976073 24 sep 16:21 LOG
$ wc -l LOG
 26144275 LOG
```

On my slow notebook the following script crunched it in 50 seconds, and produces an output like:

```
      #many lines deleted
      '022102' => {
                    'error_8' => 73,
                    'error_1' => 65,
                    # deleted lines
                    'error_3' => 67
                  },
      '091338' => {
                    'error_8' => 75,
                    #deleted....
                    'error_6' => 74
                  }
    };
```

e.g. counted each "error-type" for "each second"

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $data;
while(<>) {
    $data->{$1}{$2}++ if m/\A(\d{6})\S+\s(\S+)/;
}
say Dumper $data;
```

so, probably you don't need the grepping.

Also, check metacpan for the [File::Tail](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Tail) module (or similar), so you can run the script like with `tail -f` and counting only the incerements - what could be done in sub-second interval...